# How to treat multiple KVO messages as one for multiple changes on the properties of an object?

Tags: ios, key-value-observing

My app register Key-Value-Observing on 7 properties of Timeline class object. Each time there is a change on any of 7 properties means that the app receives one KVO message, the app will perform series of operations as update CoreData, reload the UI. Sometimes, there're up to 5 of 7 properties  has changed at same time, my app performs **duplicate** 5 series of operations and cause the app to run slowly.

For that reason, I expect to receive one message for batch changes on the multiple properties of same class, for the purpose of performing the series of operations one time. What's the approach or library to deal with problem?